# Efficient way to add element to sorted datastructure

Tags: algorithm, sorting

What is the most efficient way to add an element to a sorted data structure?

Comment: I would guess "binary search".

Comment: What kind of data structure? It could be different depending on if it's a heap, tree, list. Where do you want to add the element? At the beginning, end, or at an arbitrary location? More information is needed to properly answer your question.

Comment: @Charmander : The element values are not binary, so binary search will not be applicable. The data structure is a Red-Black Tree.

Comment: @Lanaru - Sorted order has to be maintained.

Comment: @bla: Binary search has nothing to do with whether your data is in binary form or not: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most red black tree packages will have an "insert element" method.  If you're not using one already, it might be good to start.

If you're married to a red-black tree implementation that doesn't have an insert element operation, it'd be a good idea to add such a method, possibly from some good red-black tree doc:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree

BTW, a treap is often quite a bit faster than a red-black tree, but the red-black tree will likely have less variable performance:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/python-tree-and-heap-comparison/